# list all stripe subscriptions as per price id. Like Subscription filter API

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

Can any body tell how to filter out Subscription from a particular price id. Any kind of API is present then please share here. (preferred Node.js)

Answer (score 3):

In node.js, you can list subscriptions that contain a specific price ID using the [`subscription.list()`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list) method and passing the `price` parameter, like this:

```
​​const subscriptions = await stripe.subscriptions.list({
  price: "{{PRICE_ID}}",
});
```